# Linear operator exists then differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, derivatives, transformation

Let $E_{\text{open}} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, and let $\vec{x_o} \in E$. Let $\vec{f}: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. If there exists a linear operator $A: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. such that

$$\lim\limits_{\vec{h} \rightarrow 0} \frac{||\vec{f}(\vec{x_0}+\vec{h})-\vec{f}(\vec{x_0})-A\vec{h}||}{||\vec{h}||} = 0$$

Then, by definition, $\vec{f}$ is differentiable, and $A =: d\vec{f}(\vec{x_0})$.

I'm wondering what this definition is called and where can I read more about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary to put arrows on top. These [lecture notes](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/131bh.1.03s/week7.pdf) by Terrence Tao explain the concept quite well.

Comment: Here is another post that could help too - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621949/frechet-derivative-and-linear-transformation-question

Answer (score 2):

It is called [Frechet derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative).