# Why differentiation in Rn,C are called best possible linear approximiation??

Tags: derivatives

My answer is actually it is not a linear approximiation actually it an approximation of a translation of a linear transformation..whether in complex field if we see complex as a vector space over R and if it is diff at a point then actually it behaves like a translation of a scaled rotation..then why these are called best linear approximiation though they are not linear actually a certain amount of translation of lineae are actually they....

Comment: Are you objecting to the word **linear**, as opposed to (for example) **affine**? Just say that the thing that $f'(a) \, h$ is approximating is the *difference* $f(a+h)-f(a)$, and then you really get something linear in $h$. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621949/understanding-the-derivative-as-a-linear-transformation/621995), for example.

Comment: Your question is useful. Please consider it writing in details and omitting short terms.

Comment: Sir actually i exactly don't know the defn of affine but one i heard that i recalled that a line is not passing through origin but in this case if it is then yes i meant to it here this by translation of a linear transformation though this words also seems to me not correct....

Comment: Remember that linear isn't linear ... One has to distinguish between $\mathbb R$- and $\mathbb C$-linear maps.  Both send $z$ to $a\cdot z$; in the first case $a$ is real, in the latter $a\in\mathbb C$.  Now a $\mathbb C$-linear map is, considered as a map $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ a rotation followed by a scaling.  Hence not all $\mathbb R$-linear maps are $\mathbb C$-linear.

Comment: OP are you familiar with the notion of a tangent space from multivariable calculus? You can think of the derivative as a linear transformation of the tangent line at $a$ to the tangent line at $f(a)$, and the origin of the tangent line at $a$ can be taken to be $a$. This makes it literally linear.